# How to perform Job scheduling algorithms using python?

Tags: python

Well , i want to test out which scheduling algorithm is suitable for my application , but unable to figure out on how to go about testing. i have a set of jobs to be executed , for SMP (Symmetric Multi Process ) execution i used Parallel Python , but not able to apply Job Scheduling algorithm .

For  ex:  if i want to implement SJF (Shortest Job First) how will know that the job i am submitting is the shortest compared to others , it may also happen that eventually a larger job submitted may become smaller than a relative smaller job submitted at that time.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Is your question about 1) testing, 2) Parallel Python, or 3) job scheduling algorithms in general. The problem you pose in the last paragraph is an issue with *all* SJF algorithms.

Comment: Well the problem is i want to implement a job scheduler for my application in order to run over my cluster systems , for this sake i used parallel python, apparently it does a lot implicitly . Now i would want to implement ne of the scheduling algorithm  using parallel python , but dont know how to go about doing it.

Answer (score 3):

You can only tell if the job you're submitting is the shortest if you know the runtime of all your jobs in advance. This is not an easy thing to know without first running the jobs. SJF is rarely used for this reason. Scheduling in a FIFO is much easier; you stick the jobs in a list as they come in (with `lst.append()`) and `lst.pop(0)` one off whenever you need a new job to run.

Comment: Is there any example of job scheduling using python , where i can see how its done ?

Comment: Yes: http://www.webwareforpython.org/TaskKit/Docs/Source/Docs/TaskKit.Scheduler.html